# Create new Google docs table column without resizing current ones

Tags: google-docs

When I create a new (Google docs) table column, it resizes my current ones. How can that be stopped?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your document menu go to Format > Table > Table properties.
2. On the right - section "Dimensions" - uncheck the "Column width" checkbox.
3. Try it out and have a nice day :)